# Li4S Battery Full Error - iMax B6

Tags: batteries, charger, lipo, lithium-polymer

I burnt 3 chargers (Imax B6) simultaneously by connecting Lipo 4s battery in reverse . All showing connection break error. I changed the burnt MOSFET (U5) in all chargers, one charger is recovered and works perfect but the other two charge for exact 11 seconds and then both show FULL msg on LCD. Please let me know what else I have to change to recover them?
the Charger I am using is [This](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/imax-b6-dc-charger-5a-50w-copy.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=google_gb_shopping&countrycode=GB&gclid=Cj0KCQiA5bz-BRD-ARIsABjT4ni-kdybE_GpwWmvdjmucWTk-nVME6bCyiT_Ae4jMbaXeaBo5mOXkXMaAuSsEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds&___store=en_us)

Comment: Hi, In my experience here, for this type of repair question to have any chance of being on-topic, it would be necessary for you to supply the schematic for those chargers, *as a minimum*. Can you add a link to the schematic into the question, please? Thanks.

Comment: I do not have any schematcis but I can share the charger's link I have. Link added in OP.

Comment: Sidk - Hi, Unfortunately a schematic is a *minimum* requirement for troubleshooting here. The community has decided that there is a specific closure reason for repair questions without sufficient details: "Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired. See also: [Is asking on how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/is-asking-on-how-to-fix-a-faulty-circuit-on-topic)" :-(

Comment: The IMAX B6 has been cloned, and schematics can be found on the web. eg http://www.rclab.info/2018/03/how-to-repair-your-imax-b6-charger.html